# Code for "fizzbuzz" doesn't work. Only "fizzbuzz" returned multiple times

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

Can someone please explain why the following code does not work properly? It only returns "fizzbuzz" 100 times as the answer. Thank you.

```
def fizzbuzz(number)
  idx = 0
  while idx <= number
    num = number[idx]
    if num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0
      puts 'fizzbuzz'
    elsif num % 5 == 0
      puts 'buzz'
    elsif num % 3 == 0
      puts 'fizz'
    else 
      puts num
    end
    idx += 1
  end
end

fizzbuzz(100)
```

Comment: I didn't realize that there is a subscript operator for `Fixnum`s. Very cool! http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: `num = number[idx]` what it means ? it doesnot makes sense at all

Comment: I using "number[idx]" as a passing variable. thats why I assigned it "num".
I didn't realised I should use idx as the passing variable.

Comment: @Asfand: the question is _why_ did you use `number[idx]` and not, say, `number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. `num = number[idx]`
2. The `idx` variable is the one that should be used for your checks not `num`:

   ```
   def fizzbuzz(number)
     idx = 0
     while idx <= number
       if idx % 3 == 0 && idx % 5 == 0
         puts 'fizzbuzz'
       elsif idx % 5 == 0
         puts 'buzz'
       elsif idx % 3 == 0
         puts 'fizz'
       else 
         puts idx
       end
       idx += 1
     end
   end

   fizzbuzz(100)
   ```

The above is your solution.

The reason it is always printing `'fizzbuzz'`, no matter what number you pass to the `fizzbuzz` method, is because you are assigning  `number[idx]` to the a local variable `num` where you should be using the `idx` counter in your conditional statements.

You need to print the numbers from 1 to the number you pass to `fizzbuzz`. For multiples of 3 print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of 5 print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5 print “FizzBuzz".

Comment: "because you are number[idx] to the a local variable num. The return value number[idx] is 0"

Comment: the return value of number[idx] is actually not always 0. 100[2] for example is 1. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: So is it correct to assume that it is always `0` for any `Integer` ?

Comment: No. For example: for 7[0]..[3] you get 0111  for 255[0]..[7] you get 1111 1111. For 65535 you get 1 sixteen times.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cyzanfar for your answer/help. Helped a lot. I am new to programming, just started learning.

Comment: @Cyzanfar: why would you think it is always 0? That'd make quite useless operator, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out, I've removed that part and updated my answer.